# Get value from checked input in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have complex object in React and can 't understand how to get value from checked input. There is piece of code with input. I need to add input checked value instead of words "Input value".

```
const ClientForm = React.createClass({

      .....

      render: function() {

          ......
          return(

              < AgForm.Input >
              < label className = 'myLabel' >
              < input className = "valueBroker"
              disabled = {
                readOnly
              }
              type = 'checkbox'
              name = 'is_broker'
              onChange = {
                this.form().checkbox('is_broker', true)
              }
              checked = {
                _isTrue(this.form().value('is_broker'))
              }
              />
              Agent < /label> < /AgForm.InputLine> < AgForm.InputLine error = {
                errors.system
              }
              /> < /div>


              module.exports = AddClientForm;



              const ClientListItem = React.createClass({

                    render() {

                      return

                      <div >
                        Input value {
                          (client.kind_name || '').split(',').map((type) => {
                            return <div > {
                              type
                            } < /div>
                          })
                        }

                      < /div>

                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just bind the value and the update method to the state of your component and set the actions directly on the initial input markup with the onChange handler.

Note that React is unidirectional, not bidirectional, so it can good to try to control everything *from* React *to* your rendered html and not the other way or back and forth.

Following code is from: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {value: 'Hello!'};
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: The question was about checkbox. Your answer is good but it does not relate to the question directly.The next answer by Himanshu is the correct one `event.target.checked`

Answer (score 38):

I haven't used so much react so far but I think you can get the value of checkbox using :

```
event.target.checked
```

Comment: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: @HarshaVardhini I believe you need to bind "this" to the input... `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use to catch the event

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
    handleChange(event){
       console.info(event.target.checked,
                    event.target.value, 
                    event.target.dataset.attr);
    };

    render(){
        return (
        <input
            type="text"
            value={'myValue'}
            data-attr={'attrValue'}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React `refs` to retrieve your input values:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        //... state

        this.checkBoxRef = React.createRef()
    }

    handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let isChecked = this.checkBoxRef.current.checked
        console.log(isChecked) // true | false
    }

    render() {
         return (
              <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                   <input type="checkbox" ref={this.checkBoxRef}/>
                   <button type="submit" />
              </Form>
         )
    }
}
```